# fs2 - Recurring stream that recovers upon an error

Tags: scala, fs2

I'm trying to create a fs2 stream that,

- Evaluates a function every 3 seconds and save that data into a file
- Upon an error, try to authenticate and restart the same stream
- Interrupts based on a separate stream when necessary

Below is my approach but I'm not sure whether its the best way to do so.
**I've used uppercase for the function name to highlight the place that it gets called.**

```
private def CREATE_STREAM_RECURSIVE(
     session: AuthSession,
     myService: MyService[IO],
     sessionStore: SessionStore[IO],
  ): Stream[IO, Unit] = {
    Stream
      .repeatEval(service.fetchData(session))
      .flatMap { data =>
        val jsonStream = Stream.eval(IO.delay(data.asJson.noSpaces))
        persistToFile(jsonStream) <-- another fs2 stream that writes to a file
      }
      .metered(3.seconds)
      .handleErrorWith { _ =>
        Stream.force {
          myService.login()
            .flatMap(sessionStore.setSession)
            .map(CREATE_STREAM_RECURSIVE(_, myService, sessionStore)) //recursive
        }
      }
      .interruptWhen(isItOkToInterruptStream)
  }
```

Questions:

- If an error keeps happening, is it possible for this recursion to blow the stack?
- When the interruption happens, is it possible for this stream to stop without completing the file write?
- If so, is there anyway to ensure that the file is written completely
  before the exit happens?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With help from `SystemFw`, I was able to find out answers through fs2 discord channel.

`If an error keeps happening, is it possible for this recursion to blow the stack?`

No, because that recursion is monadic and it goes through a flatMap, which in this case is hidden by `force`, and therefore it's stack safe

`When the interruption happens, is it possible for this stream to stop without completing the file write?`

Yes

`If so, is there anyway to ensure that the file is written completely before the exit happens?`

Yes, by making file write uninterruptible by transforming it into an IO and calling `.uncancelable` on it